# How to achieve spacing between containers

Tags: codenameone

Please how can I achieve this kind of spacing between containers. I also notice the containers have some kind of Bevel raise. How can I achieve that too (from code).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `Tabs` container which you can use to achieve that look. However you can do a custom version with a simple grid layout so something like this:

```
Container cnt = GridLayout.enclose(4, home, alarm, search, settings);
```

Will produce the grid effect where they take up the space. You might need to center align the buttons within that grid.

To me the line at the bottom seems like just a line in a solid color which you can achieve with the underline border on your style followed by a gray spacer.